# Tikz-graphic gets squashed in subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfiles

I try to display two tikz-plots in the same figure. But one gets totally squeezed into a small area. Here I use the same file in both subfigures, an get this result:

[image]

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
         \subfile{rgb_graph.tex}
         \caption{first graph}
     \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \subfile{rgb_graph.tex}
        \caption{second graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the loaded file **rgb_graph.tex** contains

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}    
\begin{document}    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]
  \node[state]          (1)                 {R};
  \node[state]          (2) [right =of 1]   {G};
  \node[state]          (3) [below =of 2]   {B};

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=black}} 
\tikzset{every node/.style={}} 
\path (1)     edge [->]    node[yshift=7pt]   {$c_1$} (2)
      (2)     edge [->]    node[xshift=7pt]   {$c_2$} (3) 
      (1)     edge [->]    node[xshift=7pt]   {$c_3$} (3)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your log files, and you will find error messages. Once you fix them, the document compiles.

- Add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `\path` statement in `rgb_graph.tex`.

  (Error message: `Did you forget a semicolon?`)
- Move the line

  ```
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}
  ```

  from the subfile to the preamble of the main file. Putting this command into the subfile will execute the command twice (each time you include this file), in the middle of the normal text, within the float.

  (error message: arrow `stealth'` undefined)

[image]

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
         \subfile{rgb_graph.tex}
         \caption{first graph}
     \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \subfile{rgb_graph.tex}
        \caption{second graph}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

% rgb_graph.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]
  \node[state]          (1)                 {R};
  \node[state]          (2) [right =of 1]   {G};
  \node[state]          (3) [below =of 2]   {B};
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=black}} 
\tikzset{every node/.style={}} 
\path (1)     edge [->]    node[yshift=7pt]   {$c_1$} (2)
      (2)     edge [->]    node[xshift=7pt]   {$c_2$} (3) 
      (1)     edge [->]    node[xshift=7pt]   {$c_3$} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```